# Mistaken nullable type inference (Nullable Reference Types)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-5, nullable-reference-types

Why is it that when I declare and initialize a variable using `var`, it's inferred type is nullable?

I've inserted a picture showing the object and Visual Studio's Tooltip.

[image: Nullable Object]

I would expect it's type to be `object obj` and not `object? obj`.

#### Project Setup excerpt

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>9</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.3) and Resharper is not installed.

Comment: I believe it is for backward compatibility, to not show errors for old code where some declared var like this and than set it to null.

Comment: Actually if you say `object? obj = null;` typing this on the following line would complain `var type = obj.GetType();`, but stating `var obj = new object();` does not complain. To me this is a bug in the way it is shown in the tooltip and the actual type is just `object`.

Comment: The only thing I found in the docs by searching for "var" is this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/nullable-reference-types.md#local-declarations

Comment: @Silvermind huh??? The actual type is indeed `object?`, but since compiler knows that *at that point* the value is not null it does not complain.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually the answer of the other question doesn't get me any further...

Comment: @ElMac, sorry I don't get that... How "It means that var for reference types infers a nullable reference type" is not the answer to your question? I guess I totally misunderstood what you are asking then... Could you clarify?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov actually reading the other answers answered my question. Thanks for pointing out that question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I see. Then it is merely a check of the flow that decides that it cannot be null. So they wanted for var that you can assign null later. Got it. Thanks.